# Parse Query overrides new query over old one?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I'm doing parse query to get data but new query parameter overrides old one.

In my app user can block other users. When its done I write a "Block" object to database like this

I block other user:

```
ParseObject block = new ParseObject("Block");                                
block.put("owner",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());                                                
block.put("who",otherUser);
```

when I get data I use this query.

```
    //I blocked him. dont sow me his data.
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> benblock= new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");
    benblock.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    //He blocked me dont show me his data.
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> oblock = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");                
    oblock.whereEqualTo("who",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

    query.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user","owner",oblock);  //This line doesn't work                
    query.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user","who",benblock);  //But this line does.
```

But when i retrieve data first query option

```
query.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user","owner",oblock);
```

doesnt work only last one

```
 query.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user","who",benblock);
```

works. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing this.

According to this(https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/211#issuecomment-150047052) Parse query override whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery only for the same key. Which meand I can use that parameter twice in a same query but not same key. And I just created same value with different key.

Previous my object was like this

```
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("DataClass");
    object.put("post",post);
    object.put("user",user);
```

Now It looks like this:

```
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("DataClass");
    object.put("post",post);
    object.put("user",user);
    object.put("user2",user);//same user with the above one
```

And I do query like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> benblock= new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");
benblock.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

ParseQuery<ParseObject> oblock = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");
oblock.whereEqualTo("who",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

hashtag.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user","owner",oblock);
hashtag.whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery("user2","who",benblock);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one whereDoesNotMatchKeyInQuery per key. When you add two of the same constraint for the same key, the second one is actually overriding the first. So I suggest you to use Parse.Query.and, like this:

```
//I blocked him. dont sow me his data.
ParseQuery<ParseObject> benblock = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");
benblock.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

//He blocked me dont show me his data.
ParseQuery<ParseObject> oblock = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Block");                
oblock.whereEqualTo("who", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("YouDataClass");
query1.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("user","owner",oblock);  // you will need to create two queries
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("YouDataClass");
query2.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("user","who",benblock);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(query1);
queries.add(query2);
ParseQuery<ParseObject> orQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("YouDataClass");
mainQuery.whereDoesNotMatchQuery("objectId", orQuery);
```

Comment: android doesn't have "and". Only "or"

Comment: Sorry. I haven't noticed. I've just updated the code. Can you please try this new version?

Comment: Doesn't work. Query still retrieve blocked persons data. Also seems like I cant set limit or get relational data with include method.

Comment: Hey Davi. I solved my issue check out my answer. Thank you for your time and efforts